# Access to Table Function in Another HDI Container

Tags: hana

I have one HDI container (`HDI1`) that access an Table Function (`TF_1`) in another HDI container (`HDI2`), I create the synonym, It`s OK, working fine.

But when the `TF_1` calls another Table Function (`TF_2`) in `HDI2` I get "*Insufficient Privilege*" error. I have to create a synonym to `TF_2`.

Is It Correct? Why I don`t need to do this for another object Type (E.g. Calculation Views)

Thank you

[image: Picture]

Comment: What is the definition of your table functions in `SQL SECURITY` part? I've checked scripted calculation view and its internal procedure is defined with `sql security definer`, so authorizations are not propagated inside it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it's `sql security invoker`

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced this scenario without HDI, but with plain SQL schemas and users instead.

Creating and running `TF_1` and `TF_2` as the owner of **HDI 2** is working fine.
Granting `EXECUTE` on `TF_1` to the owner of **HDI 1** works also fine. **HDI 1** can successfully run `TF_1` afterward, but not `TF_2`.

So far, so good.
With HDI the situation becomes more complex as your developer user **is not the owner of **HDI 1** schema**.
Instead, upon *activation*/*deployment* of your code, the HDI infrastructure connects as the actual owner of **HDI 1** to create the objects and then runs a series of `GRANT`s to other users, including your developer user to allow the execution of the function.

Now, in order to **grant** the execute privilege further, the **GRANT OPTION*** needs to be used in the `grant`-statement. That is a detail that is usually covered correctly by the HDI infrastructure.

In this case, however, it is clear, that the users that manage **HDI 1** do **not** have the **GRANT OPTION** to further the privilege to other users.

I recommend reviewing the activation logs, what GRANTS have been declared for the cross-container access, and look out for "missing privilege" errors during activation.

Comment: I'll try a create a new scenario with new HDI m thank you for the answer